# Dropbox Sync API authentication within application?

Tags: android, dropbox

I have downloaded the Dropbox Sync API Android. I am using it to  develop  an application. My problem is that the first time when i install /run the apk file it requires an external authentication with the Dropbox account (either through dropbox app or website).

I was wondering, can  we achieve so that the first time authentication process  of  Dropbox Sync  API with the Dropbox account is not done externally (through dropbox app or website) but within application.

I see that the access tokens are precisely for that thing but i don't see any features for access tokens at Dropbox SYNC API.

Is it possible to achieve the authentication within the application, if yes how can we do it?

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox Android Sync SDK doesn't currently offer the ability to direct where the app authorization occurs. It will automatically use whatever means the user has. That is, it will use the Dropbox app, if installed, or the web browser if not. We're tracking explicit control over this as a feature request though.

Once the app receives an access token for the user, the SDK automatically stores it for you so that you don't have to prompt the user to re-authorize the app. The SDK doesn't expose a way to retrieve the access token, but that generally shouldn't be necessary as it does the storage and loading of the access token for you. The tutorial covers this here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/start/android#linking-accounts

Comment: Thanks for the reply Greg, but i can authenticate the Dropbox account  within application with the Core API, yes? Also i want to ask you how to include the Core API in Android Studio? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Core SDK does the same authorization flow as the Sync SDK, i.e., official app or website. Installation instructions for the Core SDK are here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/android . Alternatively, you can use the Core API itself directly, without the SDK if you want, in which case you'd need to implement OAuth manually, but then you could handle the app authorization process in-app: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/45

Comment: So if i implement the OAuth manually i can make the authorization within the app?

Comment: Yes, but we don't recommend doing so.

Comment: Greg thanks for your reply, and sorry if i disturb you. But i was interested to know is the process of implementing the Core API in Android Studio the same as in Eclipse? Should i include only the dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3.jar at the libs folder within the app folder? Does that suffice?

Comment: Apologies, the Core SDK page hasn't been updated with instructions for Android Studio. Anyway, yes, I believe you should just need to add the jars to app/libs and right click and do "Add as Library".